# How do I configure and use/switch between configuration environments using Karate

Tags: testing, configuration, karate

I'm trying to configure different testing targets via `karate-config-<env>.js` files located in the same directory.

When I try to execute the tests against the different target-systems:

```
mvn test -Dkarate.env=int02 (tried: -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=int02")
```

the `karate-config-int02.js` file is not executed and the test execution gets stuck somewhere.

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#switching-the-environment), but for now I found no working example.

I am working with karate `0.9.4` on macOS with Java `1.8` in a maven `3.6.0` example-project for a prof of concept.

Extending the pom file, as shown below, was also *not* working:

```xml
<properties> 
<karate.env>int02</karate.env>
</properties>
```

I though that via the `-Dkarate.env=int02` I could ensure that the `karate-config-int02.js` would be used to configure the instance specific properties I need.

I do have a line in both karate-config files like:

> `karate.log('karate-config|karate-config-int02 is called')`

but I always see:

> `karate-config is called`

Comment: sorry I can't make out what is wrong, it all looks good. do you think you can follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and how 90% of projects do it is with just the one `karate-config.js` and then some `if else` JS logic as per the docs. Maybe you can stick to that.

```
var env = karate.env || 'dev';
var config = { someUrlBase: 'https://localhost:8080/' };
if (env == 'stage') {
  // over-ride only those that need to be
  config.someUrlBase = 'https://stage-host/v1/auth';
} else if (env == 'e2e') {
  config.someUrlBase = 'https://e2e-host/v1/auth';
}
return config;
```

Else please follow this process so we can figure out what could be wrong: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue